# Editing non-String values in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, parsing, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` which displays items which are *not* Strings, although they do have a `toString()` method and can be displayed as Strings.

I declare it as:

```java
public class AddressCombo extends JComboBox<Address> {
    public AddressCombo(ComboBoxModel<Address> model) {
        super(model);
        setEditable(true);
    }

    public AddressCombo(Address... addresses) {
        this(new DefaultComboBoxModel<Address>(addresses));
    }
    
    // Other stuff snipped
}
```

This works fine when the JComboBox is not editable, but If I make it editable then the selected item becomes a `java.lang.String` when edited which is not what we want! In addition the String might not represent a valid value at all (we have a parser that can detect this).

What is the best way to set up a JComboBox so that:

1. It manages items of a custom (POJO) type
2. It is editable
3. When the user edits the field, the user's input can be parsed with a custom parser to see if it is the correct type
4. If the input doesn't parse, it can either be corrected or a default value used
5. The selected item will therefore always be of the correct class, not a Java `String`

Comment: Create a custom combo box editor.

Comment: `JComboBox` is generic and will work with any type you want. Just be sure to declare it as `JComboBox<MyPojo>` rather than `JComoboBox<String>`. See [this tutorial](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jcombobox-basic-tutorial-and-examples) for an example.

Comment: You may also want to look at a JFormattedTextField, which (going by dim ancient memory here) can parse strings for you in addition to showing those strings in a formatted way: https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/components/formattedtextfield.html

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that is what I have done, however the selected item still becomes a String if one is entered. The linked tutorial does not seem to address an editable combo box with a custom POJO.

Comment: Please have a look at MadProgrammer's answer to a sort-of similar question: [Custom JComboBox editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17892916/). I'm not saying that this is the solution for you, but it contains great information that probably could help.

Comment: Try the Swing tutorial on [Using a ComboBox Editor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#editable). The section on "Providing a Custom Renderer" briefly mentions the ComboBoxEditor interface.

Comment: @mikera Will you [edit] your question to show a short example that illustrates what you tried?

Comment: thanks for the code. The only problem is when I try to run it I get an error because there is no `main()` method. Please give a complete example that we can copy/paste and run ourselves. Also, you should include the code that shows where a `String` is returned instead of the expected `Address`.

Comment: *public class AddressCombo extends JComboBox<Address>* You don't want or need that. You don't even need a custom renderer if `Address::toString` is crafted right. But you *do* need a custom editor as others have said

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following solution worked:

- Create a subclass of `java.text.Format` to encapsulate the formatting / parsing code
- Create a custom subclass of `BasicComboBoxEditor` to use the formatter with a `JFormattedTextField`
- Set the editor on the `JComboBox` sublass to use the above

Code for those interested:

```java
public class AddressCombo extends JComboBox<Address> {
    
    private class AddressEditor extends BasicComboBoxEditor {   
        @Override 
        public Object getItem() {
            try {
                return AddressFormat.INSTANCE.parseObject(editor.getText());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        
        @Override
        protected JFormattedTextField createEditorComponent() {
            JFormattedTextField fld= new JFormattedTextField(AddressFormat.INSTANCE);
            fld.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT_OR_REVERT); 
            return fld;
        }
    }

    public AddressCombo(ComboBoxModel<Address> model) {
        super(model);
        setEditor(new AddressEditor());
        setEditable(true);
    }

    public AddressCombo() {
        this(new DefaultComboBoxModel<Address>());
    }
    
    public AddressCombo(Address... addresses) {
        this(new DefaultComboBoxModel<Address>(addresses));
    }

    // Irrelevant stuff snipped
}
```